# It seems Ethereum dataset does not work with some token

Tags: google-bigquery, ethereum, smartcontracts, medical

In google-bigquery, could you confirm the queries with Ethereum dataset does return zero when trying to analyze, for example, [this contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x41dbecc1cdc5517c6f76f6a6e836adbee2754de3)?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: For example SELECT from_address, to_address, value, transaction_hash
FROM  `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.token_transfers` AS token_trs
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.contracts` AS contracts ON (contracts.address = token_trs.token_address)

WHERE contracts.address = ' 0x41dBECc1cdC5517C6f76f6a6E836aDbEe2754DE3 '

Comment: Yes, it's returning zero records. However, that address doesn't exists on both tables, try with `'0x3f1ddbdafd4504f3285872276ebff0d18198ae63'`

Comment: i need to analyze the medicalchain token

Comment: please, anyone could give me some information?! i really need to analyze medicalchain token with bigquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the token_address data is stored in lowercase.

Try running:

```
SELECT * FROM `bigquery-public-data.ethereum_blockchain.token_transfers`
WHERE token_address='0x41dbecc1cdc5517c6f76f6a6e836adbee2754de3' LIMIT 100
```

And you'll get results.